# Is there a way to get the files that are in a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to get the files paths in a directory that has been selected.

I use

```
//main.js
const fs = require('fs')

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    ipc.handle('files:getFiles', (direct) => getFiles(direct))
})

async function getFiles(direct) {
    fs.readdir(direct, (err, files) => {return files})
}


//preload.js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    openFile: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('dialog:openFile'),
    getFiles: (direct) => ipcRenderer.invoke('files:getFiles')
})


//renderer.js

const getFiles = (direct) => {
    let paths = await window.electronAPI.getFiles(directory)
    console.log(direct) //this line has not run because of the errors
}
```

I am running this function `getFiles('somedirectory')` in the console in the renderer console, and it spits out the error:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error invoking remote method 'files:getFiles': TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of Event`

and I am passing a string as the argument for the directory, so I do not understand why this error is being thrown.

What should I do?

Comment: Perhaps you could share a little more context, such as the output of the error you're getting? Is this an electron app? 

One thought... It looks like you made the function async, but didn't do any awaiting inside the function. Not sure if this would address your problem, but `fs` has a synchronous version of `readdir` as well that you can consider `fs.readdirSync`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it from

```
ipc.handle('files:getFiles', (direct) => getFiles(direct))
```

to

```
ipc.handle('files:getFiles', (event,direct) => getFiles(direct))
```

the first parameter is the event not the data you sent